# Installing gem error (EADDRNOTAVAIL)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, redmine

I am trying to install Redmine to a Windows Server 2012, following "[How to MANUALLY install Redmine 3.x on Windows Server 2008 R2](http://coreboarder.com/blog/?p=465)".

After installing http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ the next step is to install Bundler but I got the following error:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\redmine>ruby -v
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\redmine>gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.6)
io-console (0.4.3)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (5.4.3)
power_assert (0.2.2)
psych (2.0.8)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
test-unit (3.0.8)

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\redmine>gem install bundler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
    The requested address is not valid in its context. - connect(2) for "0.0.0.0
" port 53

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\redmine>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After poking around with ruby I noticed that uninstalling and reinstalling ruby does not remove some configs. I found a command:

```
gem env
```

This gave me the location of the configuration files. After completely deleting the directory .gem it started to work! Looks like something messed up my gem config and the defaults are right.

1. Start Command prompt with Ruby
2. Use command: gem env
3. Check GEM PATHS and locate directory .gem
4. Delete .gem directory
5. Done

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not working above Ruby 2.0.0. If I install newer version I am still getting the error. (i am using RubyInstaller)
Latest working version for me is Ruby 2.0.0-p648.

Answer (score 2):

Check your DNS is right.
If your DNS not set, gem will display below error:

ERROR:  While executing gem … (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
    The requested address is not valid in its context. – connect(2) for “0.0.0.0″ port 53

Comment: This worked for me. Windows had deleted my DNS conf. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to do this specifically?

Answer (score 1):

Found it! You need to install a **loopback adapter** on Windows. There's lots of guides on how to do it. One of the first links on DuckDuckGo is [that](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/install-loopback-adapter-windows-8-server-2012/).

Comment: Just installing it does not help for me. I am using ruby 2.1.5 if that is relevant? Do you need to configure the loopback adapter in some way? 0.0.0.0 is not a valid address to configure the loopback adapter with